# Ubuntu setting it's IPv4 address as the same adress as the feault gateway (DHCP)

Tags: dhcp

I have an `Ubuntu 16.04` machine and it is recieving its `IPv4` address from a `DHCP server`, that is also a router (running `pfSense`). Ocassionally when the machines lease expires or when it's restarted it will request a new lease, with a problem. The address it's requesting is the same address as the default gateway (in this case the `pfSense` system) has. The `DHCP server` gives an error (unknown lease), but the ubuntu machine still gives itself that address (checked using the command `ip addr`).This also seems to confuse a windows machine in the same network. I've tried removing the gateway address from `/etc/network/interfaces` in case it was getting confused. If i manually release the address (`dhclient -r <interface>`) and then get a new one (`dhclient <interface>`) it always sets a normal address, that works.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the contents of your `/etc/network/interfaces` file. for dhcp it shouldn't have the gateway information in the first place, but rather get it as part of the lease request. you might want to also look at your lease file, `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.<interface>.leases`, maybe even delete it, as it will recreate next time.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks to Doug Smythies comment.
The setup was running on vmware cloud, which has a default gateway for each network when you create it. I forgot to disable DHCP on it, which meant that both the `pfSense` router and the original default gateway were sending Ubuntu a dhcp offer. All i had to do was disable DHCP on the original default gateway and keep it on only on `pfSense`.